# App for live blogging from Blackberry to WordPress

Tags: wordpress, blog, mobile

I'm looking for an app that will let me post content to single WordPress post, inserting each new "post" either at the top or bottom of the article, with a timestamp. I know there's already an WP app for Blackberry, but I'm looking for something specifically set up for live blogging. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might look into the app [CoverItLive](http://coveritlive.com). They have software that will run on mobile devices and allow you to publish to a variety of mediums.

From what I can see, there isn't a "direct" WordPress integration, but you embed the CoverItLive feed you create into your blog. That way the users have a static location, you can update your content live that goes into the CoverItLive feed, and that way people can still comment in the normal comment section if they so desire.

Basic accounts are free.

Comment: cool, i'll check it out. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is an app Wordpress for Blackberry available from http://blackberry.wordpress.org/